# adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows

Tags: android, windows, path, adb, classpath

I set the `c:/android-sdk/tools` path to the path environment and commands like `emulator` is working just fine. But the `adb` command is still not recognized, what should I do ?

In the `path` system variable I added the `android-sdk` path and the `tools` path so far. Is there something else that needs to be done? Because commands like `adb devices` do not work. It says that the command is not recognized. By the way I want to do `adb install comeapp.apk`.

Comment: Is the `adb` right in place? It moved to `C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe` while ago

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you go to your `android-sdk/tools` folder I think you'll find a message :

> The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
>
> If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
>   launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
>   and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"
>
> Please also update your PATH environment variable to
>   include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
>   execute adb from any location.

So you should also add `C:/android-sdk/platform-tools` to you environment path. Also after you modify the `PATH` variable make sure that you start a new `CommandPrompt` window.

Comment: isn't it C:\android-sdk\platform-tools in windows ?

Comment: With newest version of android studio path is as follows: C:\Users\[youruser]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: Just add the platform-tools as an entry on your PATH variable and reboot Android Studio and it will work just fine

Answer (score 14):

If you get your adb from Android Studio (which most will nowadays since Android is deprecated on Eclipse), your `adb` program will most likely be located here:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Where `%USERPROFILE%` represents something like `C:\Users\yourName`.

If you go into your computer's environmental variables and add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` to the PATH (just copy-paste that line, even with the % --- it will work fine, at least on Windows, you don't need to hardcode your username) then it should work now. Open a new command prompt and type `adb` to check.

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that worked for me, it needed the path to have the new env variable. To add: I also had to restart Android Studio for it to take affect and work in the Android Studio Terminal.

Comment: OMG! Thank you for being so specific on the path

Answer (score 12):

You have two ways:

**First go to the particular path of Android SDK:**

1) Open your command prompt and traverse to the platform-tools directory through it such as

**$ cd Frameworks\Android-Sdk\platform-tools**

2) Run your adb commands now such as to know that your adb is working properly :

**$ adb devices** OR **adb logcat** OR simply **adb**

Second way is :

1) Right click on your My Computer.

2) Open Environment variables.

3) Add new variable to your System **PATH** variable(Add if not exist otherwise no need to add new variable if already exist).

4) Add path of platform-tools directory to as value of this variable such as C:\Program Files\android-sdk\platform-tools.

5) Restart your computer once.

6) Now run the above adb commands such **adb devices or other adb commands from anywhere in command prompt.**

Also on  you can fire a command on terminal 
**setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk\platform-tools"**

Comment: Change the first way 2nd step to: $ ./adb devices OR ./adb logcat OR simply ./adb

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is still relevant:

To run an adb command on Windows we will need to add the platform-tools path into system environment variables.

"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools"

**AppData directory is hidden generally so enable show hidden files.**

Once you get the path, add it to the system environment variables & restart the cmd, you'll get the adb commands running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just added the below path to my system `environment variables`

```
C:\Users\[YOUR-USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

You can now use the `adb` command.