# Installing apk , adb command not found

Tags: android, apk

I want to install apk on my emulator, I found this page [how to install apk](http://blog.freewarelovers.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html)  and [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows)

and my problem is when I type adb in my command line I got this:

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external commands
```

i set the `path` on windows advance, the path is the tool director in my `sdk directory`, I mean the path I set is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`, I am working on windows 7

Comment: is your eclipse environment working fine with this SDK path ?

Comment: @AndroidCoader yes , and i can run the emulator fine, and i have tree emulators 2.2, 2.3, 4.0.3

Comment: Can you copy and paste the value of your Path form Environment Variables?

Comment: @breceivemail C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, i change the path to platform-tools as one of the answers and not i got errror, device not found

Comment: see the adb.exe is in \tools exists or not ? or it is in \platform-tools folder?

Comment: @DheereshSingh it is on platform-tools folder

Comment: please paste all of path content

Comment: @breceivemail do u mean, all the folders in the platform-tools?

Comment: @breceivemail what is the content do u want please?

Comment: forget it. your first problem is solved now. now look at my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First add your Android SDK path like `"C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"` to your OS path

Second use this command to restart adb:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: i got daemon started successfully, now will i install apk again ?

Comment: use -r in your command: `adb install -r myApp.apk` for reinstalling

Comment: :( :( i got device not found :( :(

Comment: restart the windos , or kill the server ?

Comment: still the same error, see this is a print screen, am i doing right steps? http://www.mediafire.com/?0oc15s1aaiolqac

Comment: what i type `adb devices` on cmd i got this `List of devices attached`

Comment: and after that do you have any other lines?

Comment: at first restart your computer. after that disable your firewall.

Comment: are you using `adb install ...` while your emulator is open?

Comment: pllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllease , when i type all the commands i got in all questions now the eclipse doesn't open i got this error , JRE OR JDK must be avaialbe, please what happend, tomroow is my graduation project, please :((((

Comment: where are you please what happend :( ,

Comment: how can i do it, please tell me,

Comment: and where i can find it, and if i reinstall it, my project will be deleted ?

Comment: do u mean i have to reinstall eclipse? or jdk or adt or what ?

Comment: I can not solve problems related to installation. select the answer of the current question and then create new question about new problems.

Comment: i got the right answer above , the solution is that i had to instal apk while emilater is working ,and now i got sucessfull

Comment: now i want to find that instaled apk on emulator, do u know how?

Comment: go to applications in your device or emulator. if it is a keyboard go to settings-> language and input.

Comment: it is a keyboard, i got to setting , then ?

Comment: And then select the answer of your question as "Answer"

Answer (score 3):

**1 Step** If u have multiple emulator than close all emulator and open emulator by Window--> AVD Manger --> and select any one emulator on which u want to install apk and start that emulator by clicking on Strat

**2 Step** Open **Command Promot** and enter path upto folder **Platform-tools** of android sdk somethiing like cd **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools** if 64 bit other wise **C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools**

**3 Step** adb install Path Upto ur apk means path in which folder u have put apk Example **adb install  C:\User\Download\facebook.apk**

Comment: i did that and got device not found

Comment: have u open emulator on which u want to install apk first open emulator and than try

Comment: hey yes i got succeffull :) :) :) , but how can i find that apk on simulator ? it is apk for kepboard to write arabic

Comment: is u got success in install apk than u are able to see that app

Comment: @Khan Could **you** please update **your** grammar to use proper, real words? It is hard and extremely annoying to read the text you write.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

First chage your current directory to platform-tools

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

Then install your apk on emulator

```
adb install "<Path to your apk file>"
```

for example

```
adb install "c:\Apps\abc.apk"
```

Comment: i got this error: `too many files specified; only take APK file and verifier file`

Comment: Write the path to apk file in double qout. Like this:- adb install "c:\Apps\abc.apk"

Comment: This error usually occurs when your path or apk file name contains spaces and you don't write the path in double qoutes..

Comment: the name of the apk is IbrahimKeyboard.apk

Comment: and where it is present. I mean what is complete absolute path to apk file ??

Comment: it is here C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Comment: TRY THIS ON CMD: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
AND THEN :
adb install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\IbrahimKeyboard.apk"

Comment: i got device not found :( :( :( , sorry but really i did as you all told me and i don't know what to do :(

Comment: Is your emulator running properly before you type all this in cmd?

Comment: start only one emulator.. any one.. then type these commands.

Comment: pllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllease , when i type all the commands i got in all questions now the eclipse doesn't open i got this error , JRE OR JDK must be avaialbe, please what happend, tomroow is my graduation project, please :((((

Comment: please what happend , where are you

Comment: have you edited the jdk path?? try reconfiguring the jdk path in eclipse.

Comment: no , i didin't , the eclipe doesn't open , i this error when open the eclipse http://www.mediafire.com/?bgnfl55qhw6t9jc, please help me, tomorrow is the graduation project :((((

Comment: i restart and still the same erorr :(

Comment: I think you need to reconfigure jdk path in eclipse

Comment: from error message it seems like your eclipse is present on desktop/ And it is searching for java jre in eclipse\jre\bin\ Have moved any file in eclipse or somthing like that

Comment: no i didn't more any thing , i just write in cmd the command i got from these answers,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13248/discussion-between-pargat-and-totti-roma)

Comment: i am sorry , can we continue ?

Comment: thank you very much Pargat, for the path problem, i didn't restor point because the website and the android is working and i tried it, and for installing apk i make it , but now i have new problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273890/android-installed-keyboard-starts-automaticlly-on-message-not-on-edittext , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Users

1. Go to the `/Users/your-user-name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` directory
2. **./adb your-command**   (Ex: ./adb devices )

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

From

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`**

To

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`**

If doesn't work then you mught need to restart you system too.

Comment: Open Command prompt and navigate to that path then type adb it should show some help related to adb command not error :)

Comment: after restart , i got this device not found

Comment: try navigating to that directory and do ass i said in my previous comment.

Comment: did you add semicolon(';') after your path ?

Comment: are you executing adb devices ?

Comment: i don't know what is adb, but i can run these simulators, 2.2, 2.3, 4.0.3

Comment: @breceivemail when i open emulator from eclipes , yes it opens and i can program on it

Comment: can you see that device on DDMS devices?

Comment: would you tell me please how can i know if the deice on DDMS ?, and i told you that the emulator is working good and i can program on eclipse

Comment: and just one time i got this`* daemon not running . starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started sucesssfully*
error: device not found` , now i just got `error device not found`

Comment: Window->Open perspecitve ->Android->DDMS that is how you open DDMS :)

Comment: i go to folder window and didn't find open perspective folder :(

Comment: its Window menu inside eclipse not folder :)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

and

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

to your Path  Environment Variables

Comment: i tried it already , and i after that , i got `device not found`

Answer (score 0):

you can pull apk without command,
step 1 select ddms view in editor
step 2 select emulator or device 
step 3 select Fle Explorer
step 4  select sdcard and there right corner push amd pull option with device icon
          here select push option and choose your apk location and push it
step 5  now you can see your apk installed in Emulator or in device

Comment: in the first step, how can i select ddms view please?

Comment: from Eclipse Editor right top  corner select "open Perspective" and select ddms

Comment: or windows-> open Perspective

Answer (score 0):

Start terminal and write below command

For MAC

```
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
```

For Windows

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The adb command cannot be found!

Comment: that all doesn't matter. Your answer does not solve any of the OP questions. The "adb" command is not in the path, so its not accessible. How does your answer solve this problem? It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's work perfect

Go to folder android installation 
Go to platform-tools and try the below command

```
./adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

after Running your app

Answer (score 0):

For Mac - add next line to bash/zsh config file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` in my *System Path* with no luck.

I moved it to my *User Path* and it worked perfectly.

P.S. I personally use https://rix0rrr.github.io/WindowsPathEditor/, very straight forward and clean.