# android installed keyboard starts automaticlly on message not on editText

Tags: android, emulation, android-keypad

i am working with emulator,i build an application and the user have to write on arabic, i installed arabic keyboard, and it works when i want to write on message like this, when i open the message i will have just 1 keyboard, but when i type any lettle a new keyboard appear and i can use it to write arabic, the two keyboards are:
[image]

but when i want to use that installed keyboard on my application, when i start typing on edittext the second keyboard doesn't appear like this[image]

so how can i change language or how can i make the second keyboard appear?

Comment: the slide space doesn't work to change input language

Comment: now when i press and hold on the edittext , i see the choice to change input language , i selected my new kepboard but stil write just english, and still the popup keyboard doesn''t apprear, because when it appear , i can change input language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution my self, and for all how have the problem in popup the keyboard , uses this code:

```
 ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .showSoftInput(YourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```