# Installed Android SDK and ADT but command prompts not working

Tags: android, sdk, command-prompt, samsung-mobile

I have downloaded the software and installed it for Android SDK I am then adding this command into the command prompt `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` and it will not find the path.

I am not sure what to do, I don't know where platform tools sits on my computer and I am very nearly there but am completely stuck.

I have also tried most of these commands and they are not working either

[How to Use Android ADB Command Line Tool](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-android-adb-command-line-tool/)

Comment: in which drive you installed the sdk ? Have you installed it in C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools ?

Comment: Dat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows/8744960#8744960 , add folder where adt is located to your windows PATH

Answer (score 0):

To set environment variables at runtime, you can use following steps.

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```