# Error in setting virtual box for android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have set up a virtual machine for emulator and has run the android iso file and took the IP of virtual machine. Till this point everything is fine but now when I tried to to run the command "adb connect IP" my system is giving

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue actually adb.exe is in platform_tools but not in tools...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Windows. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows). In essence, right-click Computer, click "Advanced System Settings", click "Environment Variables" and include the path to the adb executable.