# Android studio: debug application on device

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I have difficulties with with debugging at Android Studio. After trying to launch application in debug mode device show alert with "Waiting For Debugger" title that never disappear. Also I have `android:debuggable="true"` in my manifest file and seems like device connected correctly, because I can simply run my application without any problem. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remove `android:debuggable="true"`, because when you run/debug an application in Android Studio is signed with a debug certificate so that setting is not mandatory.

Then check from console if the device is correctly attached with an `adb devices`. You should see it listed.

Then try in this way:

1 - close Android Studio and any other IDE you have opened (maybe you have Eclipse also running?) and emulator instances;

2 - remove USB cable from PC;

3 - run `adb kill-server` from console;

4 - open Android Studio;

5 - click on run/debug;

6 - when the window to select the device appears, attach your device to USB and USB to your computer;

Comment: @cheeesus in that case, try step 3 as first thing. Kill the server, then wait few seconds, then re-issue the `adb devices` command. Server will be restarted and you should see your devices listed.

Comment: Thank you!!! I had no idea why adb was hanging when I launched Android Studio but unplugging the device before launch worked perfectly.

Comment: Great! Works for me. Just need to say it's a bit annoying as I need to repeat it several times a day... can't the guys from JetBrains fix the tool?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik in your shell or terminal. If you have the Android Platform Tools in your path, you can run it from any location, otherwise `adb` is stored int `YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER/platform-tools`.

Comment: @fasteque , thanks one more question where do i change from MTP to PTP ? any idea ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik it depends on your android version but it should be more or less the same. On my device (Android M Preview 2), if I pull down the notifications, I see "USB for charging": clicking on it I get a popup dialog to select MTP, PTP, MIDI, ...

Comment: @NoniA. if you have the Android SDK correctly installed, that means you have to add adb and the other tools to your `PATH` variable. I don't know your environment (OSX, Windows, ...) but you can easily search for the answer in this site. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20564514/2396432, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8744758/2396432 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/17901692/2396432

Answer (score 6):

also try restarting the device - that worked for me when I had the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I have similar issue (running Android Studio on Ubuntu)

What I do:

- Close Android Studio (and Emulator(s) if running)
- Go to adb folder (/wherever_location_is/sdk/platform-tools) and run command:

  ./adb kill-server
- Open Android Studio.

Now Logcat messages appear again.

Answer (score 2):

Remove those lines related to debugging. When you launch an application from Android Studio it is signed with a debug key. Any debugging information you need can be viewed in logcat from Android Studio. Also make sure you are running the latest version (help -> check for updates) I think that's where its at.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with similar issue every day and as restarting the studio or the device is pretty time consuming (and sometimes even does not work), I was trying many things and by coincidence I found an awkward (but working) solution.

When you are in the situation when you hit debug button in Android Studio, the studio says it's connected and the device says: Waiting for Debugger, but the device waits forever, do this:

- In Android Studio, hit the 'Edit Configurations' pop-up button
- Once the Run/Debug Configurations dialog opens, the debug process starts!

Works like a miracle!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way - it works for me:

```
open
Run 
run/debug configuration 
Android app 
app  
Debugger 
Debug type 
set Auto
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i enabled the Proguard for debug!, Please disable it and try !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. After launching application, click on Run and find Attach Debugger to Android Process
[[image: You may find this helpful[1]]

Answer (score 0):

Check in gradle. if you apply proguard for debug then dubugging process not applicable to app.Make sure minifyEnabled false in debug.