# abd is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV and I need to install the OpenCV manager on my emulator. I am trying to use the abd install command in windows but abd isn't recognized. I added Android Platform tools and Android tools to my system variables and I edited the path to the location of Platform tools but abd is still not recognized. I also already had SDK. Did I miss a step?

It's also worth mentioning that the path shown in the command window is part of the path I entered but not all the way down to the platform tools.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. I have been looking at countless posts and guides but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered several times, here are some links

['adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

[adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows)

Comment: Believe me I've tried those. Nothing is working. Do you think there is something in those posts that they took for granted that I could have missed?

Comment: When adding to the system PATH file you may need to reboot your PC for these changes to take effect... Have you tried this? Can you copy your PATH that you added for the ADB? Can you also copy your installation folder for Android platform tools

Comment: I am trying to open eclipse after I restarted my computer and now I am getting an error saying that no Java virtual machine was found after looking in my adt bundle folder in my current path.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\David\My Documents\App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\ here is my path by the way

Comment: Sounds like you need to setup your java JDK path, you can find out how here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html - However sometimes you ned to uninstall the JDK and install it again

Comment: Ok I can open up eclipse again. Thanks for helping with that. abd still isn't recognized though.

Comment: I had to change my path in the process so I'm unsure how this is going to work

Comment: I found out how to change the path in the command prompt and I got it to the platform tools folder but it still doesn't recognize abd

Comment: I'm probably dyslexic. I thought it was ABD when it is actually ADB. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask and we are more than happy to help!