# React-native build - APK

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I am using two methods to build an APK in React Native project.

1. using `react-native run-android` and take the latest apk from projectFolder>android>app>build>output>apk.
2. `react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug`

then run:

```
cd android
gradlew assembleDebug
```

then physically locate the file at `android/app/build/outputs/apk` folder:

```
app-debug.apk
app-debug-unaligned.apk
```

The problem I am facing is that if I am building apk from above-mentioned methods then generated apk is not the build of updated code. But the same code which I am running on the Android simulator of Android Studio is working perfectly. Also if I am using a real device as an emulator connected to the android studio, it's running on the older version of build.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer I apologize for my way of asking help, but this was a kinda high priority issue for me... hence I was desperate to seek help from others.

Comment: can't do so..... it says you are banned from this..... i am sorry

Comment: Ah, I see. There are various instructions on the _Meta_ site to explain how to get out of an answer ban, [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+ban). It means that some of your answers (potentially including deleted ones) were not well received, and a block was automatically applied by the system. I believe you can try to tidy up recently deleted answers and then undelete them to try to attract upvotes on them, or improve existing non-deleted ones.

Comment: I've posted your solution anyway, thanks for providing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, from a comment)*.

This was solved as follows:

1. enable usb debugging.
2. download latest usb driver for phone.
3. `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk\platform-tools"` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1))
4. execute `adb. exe` from C:\Users[youruser]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools
5. run adb devices in cmd to see list of connected devices
6. Run the following in a command prompt:

   ```
   $ adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
   ```

   To find the device name, run the following adb command:

   ```
   $ adb devices
   ```