# how to solve error " 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: react-native, adb

I'm trying to run react-native app on my android device. I gave the command *npx react-native run-android* But above error appears. Any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java sdk platform tools are missing. You can manage your sdk with Android Studio.
Make sure adb is in $PATH user variable too.

Answer (score -1):

go to android directory of your  project  through command line
then run gradelw.